How To Get Actual URL Of A Telegram Mini App
It's known knowledge that telegram mini apps are just simple sites being accessed via bots. So my question is, how do i get the actual url to the site displayed when a mini app is opened? The answer is not the bot url!
I don't really know how get to that link that's why I'm here. Help me if you can please!

To obtain the real website url is very simple.
Please inspect the HTTP requests or refer to the bot's source code if available. I think you are not owner of that bot. So you have to inspect the page with browser developer tools. I attached the screenshot.

Hope it helps you.

That's it. Thanks very much.

@Knight if it answers your question, consider marking it as the correct answer

here's the syntax:
https://t.me/yourBotName?startapp=anyQueryParamYouWantToPassToTheMiniapp
hopefully this helps

This doesn't help, because i don't want to pass any query to the bot. What i want is the URL that the bot's miniapp is running on!
